# ViewPager slow swiping on Android Tablets

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an ordinary `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` containing 3 fragments, it works very smooth and beautiful on all android phones, however when I try it on Android tablets it lags while swiping from Page 0 to 1, then it works fine since I am setting `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`
. All the three fragments that are used do nothing in their `onCreateView`, they just set a layout of buttons.

Here is a snippet from my `FragmentActivity`:

```
    public void initializeMenuViewPager() {
    menuViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.menu_viewPager);
    menuViewPager.getLayoutParams().width = window_width / 3;
    menuViewPager.setAdapter(new MenuViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            createFragments()));
    menuViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}

public List<Fragment> createFragments() {
    fragmets = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmets.add(DashboardFragment.newInstance(zonesList, modesList,
            currentZone, currentMode, loadingThrobber));
    fragmets.add(CategoriesFragment.newInstance(window_width,
            window_height, currentZone.getId()));
    fragmets.add(PreferencesFragment.newInstance());
    return fragmets;
}
```

And here is my `MenuViewPagerAdapter`:

```
public class MenuViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MenuViewPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.e("MenuViewPager", "getItem " + position);
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Any help?

Comment: Try commenting everything out in the fragment, if that works then start from an end adding new elements untill you figure out what the issue is. Use a blank view for the fragment as well.